# laggy dragging (not zooming)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have an issue with D3JS when dragging. Zooming works perfectly fine, but dragging is awfully laggy.
I assume I have done something completely wrong, but I don't know what.

Here's my JS :
http://dpaste.com/394D2NT

And here's the json that I use :
http://www.filedropper.com/data_8

What baffles me is I used call on the zoom :

```
var vis = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
.style("margin", "150px")
.style("align", "center")
.call(zoom);
```

But I never called the drag. Is that something bad ?

Comment: making a fiddle or some sort of demo would be more helpful to both of us

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know about the salutations part.
About the fiddle : seems complicated given the size of the json.

Comment: @Mat Signatures are discouraged, but politeness and appreciation are not.  It depends on the admin/editor and the year if anyone ever comments on it; sometimes they let it slide, but John is right.  As for the demo, trying reconstructing your D3 chart using http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oddly enough, this "stripped" version of my code, while running on my computer, will not work jsFiddle.
I give it to you anyway : https://jsfiddle.net/wwabkb4j/